# PHP - trim values of arrays in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to trim all values of arrays, which are located in an array, but so far I am not able to use **array_walk_recursive** properly - the values aren't trimmed after the **array_walk_recursive** is run. (in this case **$test** is returning true)
This is my code so far:

```
$array = [

    [
      'component' => 'string          ',
      'productID' => 1,
      'no_cas' => '85085-34-3',
      'no_einecs' => '285-364-0',
      'isComponent' => true

    ],
    [
      'component' => 'string2       ',
      'productID' => 2,
      'no_cas' => '92128-34-2',
      'no_einecs' => '295-728-0',
      'isComponent' => true
    ],

];

function trimAll($item, $key){
    return trim($item);
}

$test = array_walk_recursive($array, 'trimAll');

var_dump('<pre>', $test , '</pre>');die;
```

Comment: `function trimAll(&$item) {$item = trim($item);}`

Comment: This works :). Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: And `array_walk_recursive` returns `bool`. Print `$array` instead.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Post that as an answer so Sasha can accept and close out his question :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
array_map(
    function(array $a) {
        return array_map('trim', $a);
    },
    $array
);
```